# SOAP path resolution for dependent XSD-file not understood

Tags: soap, xsd, jaxb, wsdl

I have two XSD-files, one is imported to the other. When retrieving the WSDL (via SoapUI) the imported xsd-file is not found.

```
Error loading [http://localhost:8294/authentication/shared-environment.xsd]:
org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: error: 
Unexpected end of file after null
```

The two of the xsd-files reside in the same folder:

```
src/main/resources
 - auth-attributes.xsd
 - shared-environment.xsd
```

The "auth-attributes.xsd" looks like this:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://dto.shared.auth.appl.com"
    xmlns:Q1="http://dto.shared.auth.appl.com"
    xmlns:Q3="http://dto.common.appl.com" elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:import namespace="http://dto.common.appl.com"
        schemaLocation="shared-environment.xsd" />
.........
.........
.........
```

The WS-Adapter is defined this way:

```
@EnableWs
@Configuration
public class BackendServerConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean 
    ServletWebServerFactory servletWebServerFactory(){
        return new TomcatServletWebServerFactory();
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean<MessageDispatcherServlet> messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
        servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
        return new ServletRegistrationBean<MessageDispatcherServlet>(servlet, "/authentication/*");
    }

    @Bean(name = "authentication")
    public DefaultWsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition(XsdSchema authenticationSchema) {
        DefaultWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();
        wsdl11Definition.setPortTypeName("SharePort");
        wsdl11Definition.setLocationUri("/authentication");
        wsdl11Definition.setTargetNamespace("http://dto.shared.auth.timetracker.appl.com");
        wsdl11Definition.setSchema(authenticationSchema);
        return wsdl11Definition;
    }

    @Bean
    public XsdSchema authenticationSchema() {
        return new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("auth-attributes.xsd"));
    }
```

I'm not really familiar with WSDL. The JAXB source generation from the XSDs is fine but the WSDL resolution fails. I't seems I need a method to tell the WSDL-building mechanism where to retrieve the imported XSDs.

Comment: Have put the imported XSD "shared-environment.xsd" to a webserver and referred it by:
 <xs:import namespace="http://dto.common.app.com"
  schemaLocation="http://<webserver>/XSD/shared-environment.xsd" />

This works. But don't like this "solution". Would like to keep definitions within the project.

Answer (score 0):

The "DefaultWsdl11Definition" has got the method **setSchemaCollection()** to register multiple XSD-definitions. I used this method instead of **setSchema** - this helped - at least a bit. The error message has gone and the Soap-requests are answered correctly.

Only, when "adding" a new project to SoapUI, the client does not create automatically requests - for whatever reason - this only works with "import" from webserver.

The WS-Configuration now looks like this:

```
@EnableWs
@Configuration
public class BackendServerConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean 
    ServletWebServerFactory servletWebServerFactory(){
        return new TomcatServletWebServerFactory();
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean<MessageDispatcherServlet> messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
        servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
        return new ServletRegistrationBean<MessageDispatcherServlet>(servlet, "/authentication/*");
    }

    @Bean(name = "authentication")
    public DefaultWsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition(XsdSchema authenticationSchema) {
        DefaultWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();
        wsdl11Definition.setPortTypeName("SharePort");
        wsdl11Definition.setLocationUri("/authentication");
        wsdl11Definition.setTargetNamespace("http://dto.shared.auth.app.com");

        wsdl11Definition.setSchemaCollection(schemaCollection());

        return wsdl11Definition;
    }

    private XsdSchemaCollection schemaCollection() {
        CommonsXsdSchemaCollection commonsXsdSchemaCollection = new CommonsXsdSchemaCollection(
                new ClassPathResource("auth-attributes.xsd"),
                new ClassPathResource("shared-environment.xsd"));
        commonsXsdSchemaCollection.setInline(true);
        return commonsXsdSchemaCollection;
    }
```